# Why isn't the sun due south at noon?

Tags: sun, time

I was going to ask a question about why the sun is not due south at noon throughout the year.  There was a discussion on this site about daylight savings time, GMT, longitude, time zone boundaries and train schedules.  I found a very interesting and more astronomical explanation here: https://darkskydiary.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/the-equation-of-time/

Comment: It's a good link, but your post isn't really a question. Please rework it as an answer to e.g. this question: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/6920/2536

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the sun reach its highest point overhead at exactly 12:00 noon?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/why-doesnt-the-sun-reach-its-highest-point-overhead-at-exactly-1200-noon)

Comment: In particular, [Henning Makholm's answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/6929/239) to the linked question specifically addresses the equation of time.